# What is dirty private memory?

Tags: linux, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I'm developing an application on a 64-bit Linux system. As I could see, my app is eating too much dirty heap memory. Talking about the heap memory, what does "dirty" mean? What makes it arise and what can be done to prevent it to arise?

**EDIT**

I'd better explain what operations my application performs.

My application runs in two threads: the first thread sends jobs to a queue which are then executed in another thread. So, the first thread allocates pages to be queued and the second thread dequeues them, executes their jobs and free them. All these operations perform in a thread-safe fashion.

So I took a test on this thing, making it queue 100000000 jobs and execute them all. Until a particular instant, the memory usage grows. Then, when the queuing process finishes and only the dequeuing one remains, memory usage inexplicably doesn't decrease. Finally, when all the jobs are dequeued and executed, all that memory is freed. So, the memory leak seems to be happening in the dequeuing process, since when it finishes all the memory is freed, but I found nothing wrong in its code.

I know it would be better if I posted my code here, but it is too large. But, from what I added, does anybody have a guess about what might be causing this?

Comment: how do you see you have "dirty heap memory" , what did you do to see it ?

Comment: @maazza I took a look into `/proc/PID/smaps`

Comment: memory leak? check with `valgrind`.

Comment: you should post an other question with your code and leave a link to this one as an introduction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking about the memory non-decrease even after freeing some chunks, you'd better use `mmap` in anonymous mode like this:

```
mmap(NULL, chunck_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

which maps no file descriptor and returns a pointer to a memory chunk which is immediately returned to the OS when you unmap it. However, `mmap` requires a system call, which is slower than malloc. So, you should use `mmap` for allocating large pages.

Comment: IIRC, `malloc` uses `mmap` for large allocations.

Answer (score 3):

I found this

> Inact_dirty: Dirty means "might need writing to disk or swap." Takes
>   more work to free. Examples might be files that have not been written
>   to yet. They aren't written to memory too soon in order to keep the
>   I/O down. For instance, if you're writing logs, it might be better to
>   wait until you have a complete log ready before sending it to disk.

Taken from here : http://www.redhat.com/advice/tips/meminfo.html

I guess it is quite like the dirty bit on I/O buffers ?
By this I mean a bit that indicates that this buffer should be written on disk because it has been modified (on linux).

Here you have a similar question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33381/getting-information-about-a-process-memory-usage-from-proc-pid-smaps

Comment: Thank you for answering. It helped a bit, but the point is I'm not performing any I/O operation... Do you know any other reason for dirty memory growing?

Comment: @LuisAntonioBotelhoO.Leite - On most "real" systems all heap is "virtual" and may be written to disk to free up RAM for other purposes.  Your "dirty memory" is growing because the application has not yet achieved steady-state.

Comment: you should not see dirty as "dirty" like in english , it just mean we need to save because it has been modified, it is not negative,it indicates that the data in memeory is not yet reflected on disk

Comment: @HotLicks I guess you are talking about what I'm looking for. But, what is steady-state?

Comment: @LuisAntonioBotelhoO.Leite - "Steady state" is a situation in a virtual memory system where the number of pages in each category tends to be relatively steady, because the rate of transitions into a category roughly matches the rate out.  This will occur when a process runs long enough without changing its execution pattern (and when the rest of the system workload is also reasonably steady).  The number of pages a process needs in this condition is known as it's "working set".

Comment: @HotLicks So, considering a multi threaded process which allocates and deallocates many many chunks of memory at the same time, can this be the reason for dirty memory growing?

Comment: @LuisAntonioBotelhoO.Leite - Every page of heap the process allocates will be marked "dirty" as soon as that heap location is written to.  If it's written to and then not referenced for a long time, the OS will "flush" it to disk to free up RAM for other uses.  If it's then referenced, "falted on", and read back in it will not be "dirty" unless and until it's modified again.  There's absolutely nothing wrong with "dirty" pages -- they indicate the process is doing work and hence the page contains changes not reflected in the disk image.

Comment: @HotLicks So dirty memory growing means memory is not being freed, right? If yes, I have a big problem, because I'm sure I'm freeing all the memory I'm allocating explicitly and for any reason there is a large amount of memory being allocated under the hood I don't know why...

Comment: dirty memory means data to be saved be not done yet it speed up the system by writing data by blocks not and by bytes because disk I/O is slow and way slower than the memory (RAM), to make it short the disk is buffered

Comment: @LuisAntonioBotelhoO.Leite - No, dirty memory is growing because your program is changing values in heap.  Or otherwise changing storage pages.  The OS is in no hurry to write out the changed pages since you're constantly changing them again and again, as you allocate new objects and delete them, so if a page was written out it would be made "dirty" again right away.  THERE IS NOTHING WRONG WITH HAVING "DIRTY" PAGES!