# Can private dirty memory be an indication of leaked memory?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an application whose memory increases with the test cases I run. This obviously led me to believe that my application is leaking memory. So I ran valgrind on my application and surprisingly it found no leaks.

I am not sure why my process's memory is leaking, so i looked at the smaps file of my process 
and below if what i found interesting

```
08426000-42f56000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
Size:             961728 kB
Rss:              960252 kB
Pss:              960252 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:    960252 kB
Referenced:       960252 kB
Anonymous:        960252 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
```

To make sense about these numbers i did some research about Private_Dirty memory, most of the articles indicate that this the memory that has not yet been freed because they are costly.

This seems to indicate that these are just memory that has freed by the application but still held back by the OS.

Can some one help me understand private_dirty better? Can this be an indication of the memory leak i have?

Thanks

Comment: Does the memory get smaller after a cleanup step and before the routine exits?  It's sounds like you are holding onto something with respect to the test cases which causes the memory to be held.  Are you using shared pointers or dealing with memory management directly?

Comment: There's a description [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17596928/2096401) of what private-dirty is: basically memory your process has "used" (written to) so that it would need to be saved if swapped-out to make space for another process.  Doesn't in itself indicate that you're leaking memory.

Comment: Maybe you are allocating lots of small size memory and then deallocating. I cannot predict much but has it got anything to do with memory fragmentation?

Comment: @Jim The memory from what i see is not getting smaller.

Comment: @Cool_Coder I am regularly allocating small size memory. With each test case i de-allocate/allocate memory.

Comment: @TripeHound I am not sure that indicates that my process is leaking memory. What i thought it represents is that process wrote into that memory and de-allocated it. But the OS has not necessarily reclaimed it.

Comment: Is this a linux system?  Linux notes when memory has been used which kinda seems like a program is using it, but it's not.  Have you run yur program to completion and looked at the valgrind results?

Comment: @Jim Yes, this is a Linux System. My process is a never ending process. I added support for a clean exit and viewed the result. No memory leaks

Comment: The you probably don't have any leaks.  Is performance suffering?  Other than the dirty private memory, why did you think you were leaking?

Comment: @Jim, i reran the test upteen number of times. It eventually reached the 4GB limit and crashed. Thats my worry

Comment: You probably don't have a memory _leak_ -- in the sense of memory that hasn't been freed but to which you no longer have a reference/pointer -- but it sounds like you may have what might be termed a _memory accumulation_ -- you're constantly allocating new space for new data, but not freeing/deallocating/dereferencing old memory that you no longer need. I'd look closer at where you _think_ you're freeing memory you no longer need.

Comment: You seem to be doing something that doesn't force disk writes (dirty page accumulation) except at the end when you built a clean exit.  Somewhere you are not keeping up with your bookkeeping.  Maybe flush some file pointers?  Or close and reopen them?

Comment: @Jim, I do open a lot of files and close them. Maybe i am leaking something there or not handling them exactly right.

Comment: @TripeHound Maybe. I will try to use valgrind and see if there is pattern to my increase in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be memory waiting to be written to disk, for which the system is taking some time doing so.  Your program must be producing lots of results that are written out to disk files.

[What is dirty private memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762515/what-is-dirty-private-memory)